# Laravel updating a hasMany relation column with an array of strings

Tags: php, laravel

I have found a way to do this with 2 SQL queries, one for delete and the other one is mass creation, but this is not a solution, I will need to update those relations via update with one query and eloquently, if possible.

#### Premise:

- `search` has many `board_names`
- receiving an array of board_names: `$query->board_names = ["one", "two"]`;
- `board_names` table has a `board_name` column and a `search_id` foreign key.

```
$updatedBoards = [];
        foreach ($query->board_names as $board_name){
            $updatedBoards[]['board_name'] = $board_name;
        }

        $search->boardNames()?->delete();
        $search->boardNames()->createMany($updatedBoards);
```

I am looking to write the above **as an update**, eloquently (if not then with `queryBuilder()`) and **with one SQL query** (if possible).

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question?

Comment: @AbdullahAfridi - be more specific on what you didn't understand

Comment: The question here is, how do you want to retrieve target records? Because to update a record, you must first find it based on a where condition, and then update its values. In your scenario, I don't see any fields that you can use to find records that need to be updated.